# connect Flutter code from different sources like for example youtube tutorials

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, navigationbar

Hello Guys im new to flutter.

To understand Flutter I watched a lot of videos and read blog entries. 
But there is always a problem: 
Each video is about a specific topic and all of them start with a new Flutter project.  As long as I want to continue working on the code I can't change the code.

Below I have added a code by Hanz Müller as an example.  Topic NavigationBar.

But now I want to delete the text under the icons and edit the different app pages (body) with text and images. 
I can't delete the text under the icons because text can't be ''null''. 
And I can't edit the diffrent body pages because I can't find the position.

i only know html and css because it is a hobby and now i search for the place where i find the body container :)

Thanks a lot for your help

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class Destination {
  const Destination(this.title, this.icon, this.color);
  final String title;
  final IconData icon;
  final MaterialColor color;
}

const List<Destination> allDestinations = <Destination>[
  Destination('Home', Icons.home, Colors.teal),
  Destination('Business', Icons.business, Colors.cyan),
  Destination('School', Icons.school, Colors.orange),
  Destination('Flight', Icons.flight, Colors.blue)
];


class DestinationView extends StatefulWidget {
  const DestinationView({ Key key, this.destination }) : super(key: key);

  final Destination destination;

  @override
  _DestinationViewState createState() => _DestinationViewState();
}

class _DestinationViewState extends State<DestinationView> {
  TextEditingController _textController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _textController = TextEditingController(
      text: 'sample text: ${widget.destination.title}',
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('${widget.destination.title} Text'),
        backgroundColor: widget.destination.color,
      ),
      backgroundColor: widget.destination.color[100],
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: TextField(controller: _textController),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _textController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin<HomePage> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        top: false,
        child: IndexedStack(
          index: _currentIndex,
          children: allDestinations.map<Widget>((Destination destination) {
            return DestinationView(destination: destination);
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        onTap: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            _currentIndex = index;
          });
        },
        items: allDestinations.map((Destination destination) {
          return BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(destination.icon),
            backgroundColor: destination.color,
            title: Text(destination.title)
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: HomePage(), debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the Text under the icon Check the code where the `Text` widget is place.

So you have the relevant `Text` widget in `BottomNavigationBarItem`

```
title: Text(destination.title)
```

So if you don't need the `Text` widget you can simply replace it with Container to display nothing.

```
title: Text(destination.title)
```

I would suggest you read the code and understand it will. The better you understand how your widgets are built and rendered it will be easier to modify them.

Comment: that helped me a lot.  Thanks a lot. 
I suppose I can edit the body part of each page in the same way (after pressing an icon, another page opens) ? Im looking for the Widget build(BuildContext context) remove the child: TextField(controller: _textController), and add a container(), ?

Comment: It actually depends on what you are trying to build and there will always be multiple approaches. I suggested replacing `Text` with `Container` because  `BottomNavigationBarItem` requires `title` to be passed or else it will throw an error. You can replace the body of the scaffold for changing pages through `BottomNavigationBar`.If you want to open new pages on top of your current page then you have to use Navigator.